# Java HashSet add() method is not calling overridden equals() method

Tags: java, equals

I have this code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    System.out.println("equals called");

    if(this == obj) {
        System.out.println("THIS object is the same as OBJ");
        return true;
    }

    System.out.println("obj.getClass() is " + obj.getClass());
    System.out.println("this.getClass() is " + this.getClass());
    if ((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }

    double objOrbitalPeriod = ((HeavenlyBody) obj).getOrbitalPeriod();
    return this.orbitalPeriod == objOrbitalPeriod;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}
```

In Main code is:

```
private static Set<Planet> solarSystem = new HashSet<>();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Planet planet = new Planet("Earth", 365.0);`
    solarSystem.add(planet);
    solarSystem.add(planet);
}
```

Can someone explain why its not printing anything?

I would expect it should print:
`"equals called"`

and (as it is a duplicate):`"THIS object is the same as OBJ"`

But it seems there is something going on that I cannot understand.

Comment: I see `HeavenlyBody` in your code instead of  `Planet`

Comment: Try Set<HeavenlyBody> instead of Set<Planet>

Comment: In which class is `I have this code` ?

Answer (score 5):

Well, `HashSet` is implemented using `HashMap`. And in the implementation of `put` in `HashMap`, it locates the node with the appropriate hash, and then checks this:

```
if (p.hash == hash &&

    ((k = p.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))

    e = p;
```

This means that it first checks object identity, and only if the objects are not identical, it calls the `equals` method. Since your objects are identical, the `equals` method is not called.

[Source of `HashMap`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java)

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of `HashMap`  (internal implementation of a `HashSet`), there is a if condition which shows that if two keys are the same reference, there is no need to call `equals`.

```
...
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
    break;
...
```